# SQL query column alias name with concat does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, alias, concatenation

If I try to add alias name to a column name when using sql concat along with html tags it fails with error. Please find below the details.

1) CountryDtls Table

```
Id |CountryName |CityName  |
---|------------|----------|
1  |India       |Mumbai    |
2  |India       |Chennai   |
3  |India       |Bhopal    |
4  |India       |Indore    |
5  |Aus         |Sydney    |
6  |Aus         |Melbourne |
7  |USA         |NY        |
8  |USA         |Chicago   |
```

2) Working query

```
SELECT 
      CONCAT("",
           GROUP_CONCAT(
                CONCAT("",CountryName,"
"),
                CONCAT("",CityName,"")
           )
      ,"") AS html FROM CountryDtls;
```

3) Result

```
<div><span>India</span><br/><span>Mumbai</span>,<span>India</span><br/><span>Chennai</span>,<span>India</span><br/><span>Bhopal</span>,<span>India</span><br/><span>Indore</span>,<span>Aus</span><br/><span>Sydney</span>,<span>Aus</span><br/><span>Melbourne</span>,<span>USA</span><br/><span>NY</span>,<span>USA</span><br/><span>Chicago</span></div>
```

4) Query with column name alias

```
SELECT 
      CONCAT("",
           GROUP_CONCAT(
                CONCAT("",CountryName,"
"),
                CONCAT("",(CityName AS City),"")
           )
      ,"") AS html FROM CountryDtls;
```

5) Error thrown back

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS City),"")
           )
      ,"") AS html FROM CountryDtls' at line 5
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS City),"")
           )
      ,"") AS html FROM CountryDtls' at line 5
```

Comment: Why you want to use an alias on this position?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but what are you trying to achieve? Because that alias in there makes no sense. If you want it to be a part of your html you need to add it to the concat as a text, like:

`CONCAT("",(CityName)," AS City")`